# how to transform the data between different form?

Tags: r

Data1 is one the web,
[the data is data1](http://stats.math.uni-augsburg.de/Mondrian/Data/Titanic.txt)
http://stats.math.uni-augsburg.de/Mondrian/Data/Titanic.txt

when i got data1,how can i get the table(name it data2) as under:

```
, , Age = Child, Survived = No

      Sex
Class  Male Female
  1st     0      0
  2nd     0      0
  3rd    35     17
  Crew    0      0
```

and when i have data2 as under:
    , , Age = Child, Survived = No

```
      Sex    
Class  Male Female    
  1st     0      0    
  2nd     0      0    
  3rd    35     17    
  Crew    0      0    

, , Age = Adult, Survived = No    

      Sex    
Class  Male Female    
  1st   118      4    
  2nd   154     13    
  3rd   387     89    
  Crew  670      3    

, , Age = Child, Survived = Yes    

      Sex    
Class  Male Female    
  1st     5      1    
  2nd    11     13    
  3rd    13     14    
  Crew    0      0    

, , Age = Adult, Survived = Yes    

      Sex    
Class  Male Female    
  1st    57    140    
  2nd    14     80    
  3rd    75     76    
  Crew  192     20
```

How can i transform data2 to be data1?

1.transform data1 to be data2
i can do part of  work.

```
url <- 'http://stats.math.uni-augsburg.de/Mondrian/Data/Titanic.txt'
data <- read.table(url,T)
data[data$Age=="Child" & data$Survived =="No",][,c(1,3)]
```

2.transform data2 to be data1
don't know how to do.

i don't want to  get the subdata of Titanic from Titanic .
How can i get the Titanic table from a csv file?
How can i get a csv file from Titanic table?

when i write Titanic into a file ,the data form is not the same in the web
`http://stats.math.uni-augsburg.de/Mondrian/Data/Titanic.txt`
i optn what i write in :

```
    "","Class","Sex","Age","Survived","Freq"    
    "1","1st","Male","Child","No",0    
    "2","2nd","Male","Child","No",0    
    "3","3rd","Male","Child","No",35    
    "4","Crew","Male","Child","No",0    
    "5","1st","Female","Child","No",0    
    "6","2nd","Female","Child","No",0    
    "7","3rd","Female","Child","No",17    
    "8","Crew","Female","Child","No",0    
    "9","1st","Male","Adult","No",118    
    "10","2nd","Male","Adult","No",154    
    "11","3rd","Male","Adult","No",387    
    "12","Crew","Male","Adult","No",670    
    "13","1st","Female","Adult","No",4    
    "14","2nd","Female","Adult","No",13    
    "15","3rd","Female","Adult","No",89    
    "16","Crew","Female","Adult","No",3    
    "17","1st","Male","Child","Yes",5    
    "18","2nd","Male","Child","Yes",11    
    "19","3rd","Male","Child","Yes",13    
    "20","Crew","Male","Child","Yes",0    
    "21","1st","Female","Child","Yes",1    
    "22","2nd","Female","Child","Yes",13    
    "23","3rd","Female","Child","Yes",14    
    "24","Crew","Female","Child","Yes",0    
    "25","1st","Male","Adult","Yes",57    
    "26","2nd","Male","Adult","Yes",14    
    "27","3rd","Male","Adult","Yes",75    
    "28","Crew","Male","Adult","Yes",192    
    "29","1st","Female","Adult","Yes",140    
    "30","2nd","Female","Adult","Yes",80    
    "31","3rd","Female","Adult","Yes",76    
    "32","Crew","Female","Adult","Yes",20
```

the data is not what i want to get.

Comment: You do realize that `Titanic` is included in R automatically, right? So there's no need to read it in from a url...

Comment: i just want to learn knowledge on R to transform data.

Comment: Put `quote = FALSE` into your `write.csv` call to eliminate the quotes in the resulting file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but it seems like you want to know how to specify the order of what's tabulated in a mulit-dimensional table.

If that is the case, try this (first rows, then column, then third dimension (age), then fourth dimension (survived)):

```
data2 <- table(data[c("Class", "Sex", "Age", "Survived")]) 
## table(data[c(1, 3, 2, 4)])
data2
# , , Age = Adult, Survived = No
# 
#         Sex
# Class    Female Male
#   Crew        3  670
#   First       4  118
#   Second     13  154
#   Third      89  387
# 
# <<SNIP>>
#
#
# , , Age = Child, Survived = Yes
# 
#         Sex
# Class    Female Male
#   Crew        0    0
#   First       1    5
#   Second     13   11
#   Third      14   13
```

As to the second part of your question, it sounds like "how do I recreate a flat/rectangular `data.frame` from tabulated data. For this particular example, you can try something like:

```
X <- data.frame(data2)
X <- X[rep(rownames(X), X$Freq), -length(X)]
```

Compare the `summary` of the recreated data with the `summary` of the original data:

```
summary(X)
#     Class         Sex          Age       Survived  
#  Crew  :885   Female: 470   Adult:2092   No :1490  
#  First :325   Male  :1731   Child: 109   Yes: 711  
#  Second:285                                        
#  Third :706  
summary(data)
#     Class        Age           Sex       Survived  
#  Crew  :885   Adult:2092   Female: 470   No :1490  
#  First :325   Child: 109   Male  :1731   Yes: 711  
#  Second:285                                        
#  Third :706
```

Then again, I'm shooting in the dark, because your question isn't very clear. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

`Titanic` is a "table" object, so you'll want to explore it a little bit to understand what you're looking at:

```
> str(Titanic)
 table [1:4, 1:2, 1:2, 1:2] 0 0 35 0 0 0 17 0 118 154 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 4
  ..$ Class   : chr [1:4] "1st" "2nd" "3rd" "Crew"
  ..$ Sex     : chr [1:2] "Male" "Female"
  ..$ Age     : chr [1:2] "Child" "Adult"
  ..$ Survived: chr [1:2] "No" "Yes"
> dim(Titanic)
[1] 4 2 2 2
> dimnames(Titanic)
$Class
[1] "1st"  "2nd"  "3rd"  "Crew"

$Sex
[1] "Male"   "Female"

$Age
[1] "Child" "Adult"

$Survived
[1] "No"  "Yes"
```

Use those `dim`s and `dimnames` to extract the part of the table you want:

```
> Titanic[,,'Child','No']
      Sex
Class  Male Female
  1st     0      0
  2nd     0      0
  3rd    35     17
  Crew    0      0
```

For the data as you've loaded it from the web, you just want to wrap your last line of code in `table`:

```
table(data[data$Age=="Child" & data$Survived =="No",][,c(1,3)])
```

Comment: you get the subdata of Titanic from Titanic ,how can i get the Titanic table from a csv file?and how can i get a csv file from Titanic table?

Comment: As I said above, `Titanic` is already in R. Just type `Titanic` in your console. Look at `write.csv` for writing it to a CSV file.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature, is [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20097758/1270695) along the lines of what you're trying to do?